# eigenvalue and rank of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

what i feel is that since the range of the linear transformation is strictly less than $n$ this implies that the transformation is not onto hence the null space contains a non trivial vector.but is any other option correct i am not able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right.

D is false : take any non zero x in $V_1$ as eigenvector for the eigenvalue 0, so there is another eigenvalue in addition to $\lambda$.

T is not invertible because, eg, not onto between two space of same dimension, hence also its determinant is 0, so can't be A.

Comment: Thnku for the answer

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.